# Django links to other other apps

Tags: django, django-views

Maybe this question has been answered before in one way or another. But I need to ask because I tried to answer it myself I googled it for days but I couldn't figure it out.

I have an app called reception in my Django project.

I figured out everything but this.

I have the link in the html directing to the right urlpattern.

```
 <p><tab1><a href="{% url 'go_to_reception' %}">Reception</a></tab1></p>


urlpatterns = [...,  path('go_to_reception', views.reception, name='go_to_reception'), ...]
```

And the view is like this

```
def reception(request):
    return render(request, 'reception.html')
```

now instead of reception.html I want the link to go the reception page. The app page. What do I need to write there. I have tried everything that came to my mind but nothing worked.

the reception is as follows:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/reception/

So how do I point to this.

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand what you mean by "I would like for it to point to the reception app." Can you try to explain with a scenario?

Comment: Others can't see your example as the URL you posted is local. [See this](https://www.lifewire.com/network-computer-special-ip-address-818385).

Comment: I am sorry it is actually hard to explain since I am not using the right terminology. So now: if the server is running it goes to this page right? 172.0.0.1:8000. Now my homepage is set and from that homepage I want to create a link that goes directly to the app "reception". How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So im just going to write the solution that we discussed in the chat:

{% url "admin:app_list" app_label="reception" %}

[documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls)

Answer (score 0):

Look, this help you? i solve a similar problem in this way

url.py

```
path('gotoreception', views.reception, name="go_to_reception"),
```

html

```
<a href="{% url 'go_to_reception' slug=slug %}"
```

model

```
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

view

```
def home(request, slug):
context = {'yourdata':yourdata}
    return render(request,'index.html', context)
```

On the template tag url you need use the name of your path, you can use a slug if you store the field on your db

3º option but not recommended, you can add the value if you have on a variable but is not a good practice

I recommend you this 2 resources:

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/
2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/

> hardcoded way

can you test this?
urls

```
urlpatterns = [...,  path('reception/', views.reception, name='go_to_reception'), ...]
```

html

```
and on the link <a href="127.0.0.1/reception/">
```

is the hardcoded way but in the future you can have troubles or relative urls, 404 on internal pages

Comment: Thanks for your help but your solution didn't work. It comes back with this error: _Reverse for 'go_to_reception' with keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['go_to_reception$']_. I do assume you have typo there, "gotoreception" without any underscores. Well it doesn't work either way.

Comment: its because we need more infor for help you, i add more details on the answer maybe this give you a better vision

Comment: I do honestly appreciate your help. But I don't understand what you mean. I am really new to this. I made quite a lot of progress for a beginner but I still don't understand minute little details. Is there another of doing this than slugs?

Comment: can you test this?
urlpatterns = [...,  path('reception/', views.reception, name='go_to_reception'), ...]
and on the link <a href="127.0.0.1/reception/">

is the hardcoded way but in the future you can have troubles or relative urls, so 404 on internal pages

Comment: It came back with this message: _Reverse for '127.0.0.1/reception/' not found. '127.0.0.1/reception/' is not a valid view function or pattern name._ So it is not working. I honestly don't expect it to be hard coded. How do you create links that conntect to "apps"? That is actually the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer Matthew,

After your latest comment, I have changed my code to the following:

```
<p><tab1><a href="{% url 'reception:go_to_reception' %}">Reception</a></tab1></p>
```

and in url.py its:

```
path('reception/', include('reception.urls', namespace='reception-urls')),
```

in reception.urls.py

```
app_name = "reception"
```

and the message now says:

django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'go_to_reception' not found. 'go_to_reception' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I am sorry for going back and forth like this, but I honestly can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

have you got a view called go_to_rececption in your reception.views or a url named go_to_reception in your reception.urls?.

and no worries just trying to help!!!

Comment: Thank you, in that case do you mind switching to messaging ?